# Authenticate from external site

Tags: php, asp.net, http, session, authentication

Firstly i have tried to google all my questions of this but has not found the solution to my answer. I am trying to either use and existing browser session or authenticate if the  session does not exist.

I have Site A: https://mysite.com/Login.aspx  This site is the site i am trying to either use existing browser session or authenticate with if no session exists

Site B: http://myinternalsite.com/work.php   This is my internal site that i am trying to build so i can perform some function against Site A

I first thought that i could use jquery jsonp post to the site which i think i can do but it must first be authenticated or Site A will just redirect all posts to the login page. I have used external third party ui testing sites that use basic http authentication to take screenshots of my Site A but im unsure how to replicate that authentication process on my end.

Im looking for a direction or example to get me in the right direction, it seems like it should be easy enough but ive never used authentication in php so i am lost :(

Comment: There is something which is confusing me... does site A use its own login system or basic HTTP authentication? And what do you mean by browser session? PHP session on site A or what exactly?

Comment: From what my developer says Site A is using Forms Authentication

Comment: Then you'd better tag this question as ASP.NET too. You most probably need to use curl on the PHP side, but you can't do anything if you don't know exactly how it happens on site A.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exact solution but it might lead you to the correct path. I had similar problem.

I had 2 websites and from second website i wanted to monitor website 1. Meaning i wanted to get all statistics, users online, updates, page visits etc... from website 1 to website 2.

To achieve this i created a Sender.php controller inside website 1 (note im using MVC framework). Sender.php was grabbing all information above and was posting to website 2 using **cron job**.

I had Reciever.php in website 2 where all above data was posted. All i had to do in Reciever.php is to grab data, sanitize it and display on screen as statistics.

Comment: That sounds like it would work but the only problem is that i dont have access to the source code for Site A :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but I'll give you an example of what I think you want to do.

site 1

Your aspx form, sending login information or session information to site 2

site 2

Retrieve that information sanitize it, and check it against for example a database if that user exists and or if the user session send by site 1 is logged in.
you could use a authenticate function, checking the database to see if session or users exists

site 2

```
<?php
    $user_is_loggedin = 1; // this should come from database or function check user
    if ($user_is_loggedin == TRUE) {
     echo 1; // return user id, current session stored in database on site2
    } else {
     echo 0;
    }
?>
```

site 1:
dont know aspx so..

```
if (reponse == FALSE ) {
 //REDIRECT TO LOGIN
} ELSE {
 // Do whatever you would like with that reponse
}
```

Comment: Well site 1 is our main application that users log into and perform their day to day functions. The reason i want site 2 to access site 1 is sort of a work around to site 1 not having an API to  do client specific task (ie. create users, buildings). So im trying to create something simple to help our internal users by having this internal php page(site 2) that will post data to site 1